# Editing the Text of Word Document Range removes paragraph formatting

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto, add-in, office-interop

I'm using Office Interop with MS Word (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word) and Microsoft.Office.Tools.Word to modify a word document in a Word Add-in. I have a Range which contains specific text I want to edit.

When I update the Text object, the paragraph formatting of the Range is reset, specifically the Alignment and the LeftIndent. I can save the Alignment and LeftIndent in temp variables and reset them, but this is not ideal. **Is there a way to stop the ParagraphFormat from being reset and if not, are there any other properties that I may be forgetting that I need to save (I *just* realized the before and after paragraph spacing also gets reset...).**

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range range = myObject.range;
var oldAlignment = range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment;
var oldLeftIndent = range.ParagraphFormat.LeftIndent;

range.Text = "new text";
range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = oldAlignment;
range.ParagraphFormat.LeftIndent = oldLeftIndent;
```

**Edit:** I just tried saving the ParagraphFormat as a temp variable and then resetting the formatting with that, but the temp variable loses its formatting as well.

```
oldParagraphFormat = range.ParagraphFormat;
range.Text = "new text";
range.ParagraphFormat = oldParagraphFormat; // oldParagraphFormat's objects are reset
```

Comment: which temp variable loses its formatting..? oldAlignment or both oldAlignment and oldLeftIndent..?

Comment: Neither. The edit means I tried doing var oldParagraphFormat = range.ParagraphFormat, which didn't work. I'll reedit my question to make that clear.

Comment: it appears that you are just reassigning the values to oldAlignment and oldLeftIndent you may want to investigate how to add New ParagraphFormat.Alignment as a hint..

Comment: @DJ KRAZE Reassigning the properties is not a problem. You're probably right that I should be creating a new object for Alignment, however, LeftIndent (and SpaceBefore, SpaceAfter, and LineSpacing) all are floats. I've discovered that SpaceBefore, SpaceAfter, and LineSpacing are also being reset so I need to also keep track of them as well.

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't solve my problem. I'm not doing anything that complicated. I'm not creating any paragraphs or ranges, I'm literally just taking an existing Range and changing it's Text. As I stated, when I do this simple thing, the Range's ParagraphFormat gets reset to the default values.

Comment: To confirm this, I removed the one simple line `range.Text = "newText";` from my code, and the Range's format did not change.

Comment: myObject.range what is the value and or how are you instantiating myObject ..?

Comment: Range from Paragraph.Range, Paragraph from the list of Section.Range.Paragraphs, Section from the list of Document.Sections, Microsoft.Office.Tools.Word.Document from Globals.Factory.GetVstoObject(iDocument), Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document iDocument from Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application.ActiveDocument. myObject is ThisAddIn.cs (my code is a Word Add-in). I was trying to simplify the example and focus on the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try creating a duplicate of the `Range.ParagraphFormat` object prior to changing the text. You can do this via the [ParagraphFormat.Duplicate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word._paragraphformat.duplicate.aspx) object. This will retain the old ParagraphFormat value. After you change a range's text and its ParagraphFormat resets, you can restore the value from the duplicate.

```
// Get current value of ParagraphFormat.
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range range = myObject.range;
var oldParagraphFormat = myObject.range.ParagraphFormat.Duplicate;

// Change the range's text. This will reset ParagraphFormat, so reapply the previous value.
range.Text = "new text";
range.ParagraphFormat = oldParagraphFormat;
```

**Some background as to what's going on:** Changing `Range.Text` essentially resets the Range object because a Range is text + formatting. So changing the text without including any formatting information will cause all previous formatting to be lost. (Much like how changing an HTML tag's innerText property causes that tag to lose all child tags.)

If duplicating the ParagraphFormat doesn't help then you may want to look into setting the [Range.FormattedText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.range.formattedtext.aspx) property instead of Range.Text.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. I can't believe I missed Duplicate. Thanks Keith for the explanation as well.