# Formatting removed when replacing text from word document header part

Tags: c#, vb.net, ms-word

I am creating an application which takes document and replaces some parameters with given values. The problem is when i replace the parameter value `@CCompany` with any text the formatting is getting removed. The actual document is looking like this.

[image]

Then after replacing the `@CCompany` parameter the color of that parameter and lines are getting removed.

In the following screen shot the `20142015` is the value which has been replaced from `@CCompany` parameter.

[image]

The code to replace the document header text i am using is here.

```
foreach (Word.Section section in myDocUpdate.Sections)
{
    Word.Range headerRange = section.Headers[Word.WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterPrimary].Range;
    headerRange.Text = headerRange.Text.Replace("@CCompany", '20142015');
}
```

My requirement is when i replace the parameter with assigned value then formatting should not be removed. What should i do for this? is there any other way to do this? for example using `field` or `textarea`. But, it is mandatory that the header text is must be written in Word Document Header.

Thanks in advance, Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: just to clarify >  your output shold be `EMPLOYMENT AGREEMENT | 20142015`, Right?

Comment: yeah right. it should be displayed same as above screen shot. just value should be replaced and formatting should not be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After lof tries finally i got the solution. But, it doesn't mean that the solution is given by  *raj*  was not helpful. yeah it can work also. but, unfortunately the design of my document was very complex. So whenever i try to replace the value from the header part. the document removes the format which i have given to that parameter(@CCompany).

I have done it by using **Field** (Insert->Quick Part->Field). Now, it works fine.

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.HeadersFooters headers = section.Headers;
foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.HeaderFooter header in headers)
{
    Word.Fields fields = header.Range.Fields;
    foreach (Word.Field field in fields)
    {
        //I can check also the field text which i want to replace 
        //if there are multiple fields created with different value
        if (field.Type == Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdFieldType.wdFieldUserName)
        {
            field.Select();
            field.Delete();
            wordApp.Selection.TypeText("Company Name");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try making a copy of the current formatting using [ParagraphFormat.Duplicate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838308(v=office.15).aspx) and restore it after you change the text. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12828560/editing-the-text-of-word-document-range-removes-paragraph-formatting)'s an example.

```
foreach (Word.Section section in myDocUpdate.Sections)
{
    Word.Range headerRange = section.Headers[Word.WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterPrimary].Range;
var oldHeaderFormat = headerRange.ParagraphFormat.Duplicate;
    headerRange.Text.Replace("@CCompany", '20142015');
    headerRange.ParagraphFormat = oldHeaderFormat;
}
```